# Compare two columns and identify character difference in R

Tags: r, character, string-matching

I am trying to write a program that examines two columns of text and identifies single errors. For example:

```
 1    2  
bat  bad  
tap  ta  
tap  tape
```

I would like the program to compare column one against column two, and to print the character difference.

Comment: Add some of your code first. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See `?agrep` and `?adist`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach using the `stringdist` package.

```
# Your data sample, plus a couple of extra rows
dat = data.frame(x=c(1,'bat','tap','tap','tapes','tapped'), 
                 y=c(2,'bad','ta','tape','tapes','tapas'))

dat
       x     y
1      1     2
2    bat   bad
3    tap    ta
4    tap  tape
5  tapes tapes
6 tapped tapas

library(stringdist)

# Distance methods available in stringdist
dist.methods = c("osa", "lv", "dl", "hamming", "lcs", "qgram",
                 "cosine", "jaccard", "jw", "soundex")

# Try all the methods with the sample data
sapply(dist.methods, function(m) stringdist(dat[,1],dat[,2], method=m))
```

> ```
>      osa lv dl hamming lcs qgram    cosine   jaccard         jw soundex
> [1,]   1  1  1       1   2     2 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.00000000       1
> [2,]   1  1  1       1   2     2 0.3333333 0.5000000 0.22222222       0
> [3,]   1  1  1     Inf   1     1 0.1835034 0.3333333 0.11111111       1
> [4,]   1  1  1     Inf   1     1 0.1339746 0.2500000 0.08333333       0
> [5,]   0  0  0       0   0     0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000       0
> [6,]   3  3  3     Inf   5     5 0.3318469 0.5000000 0.30000000       1
> ```

Or, using `adist`, as suggested by @thelatemail:

```
apply(dat, 1, function(d) adist(d[1], d[2]))
```

> ```
> [1] 1 1 1 1 0 3
> ```

`adist` uses the Levenshtein distance, equivalent to the `lv` method above. This is probably the method you want.

For explanations of the different distance methods, see [this web page](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/comparison-of-string-distance-algorithms/).

Answer (score 1):

here is the code, i think this is you are expecting.

```
df
  one  two
  bat  bad
  tap   ta
  tap tape

getDiff<-function(dataframe){
  result<-" "
  for(i in 1:nrow(dataframe))

    str1<-unlist(strsplit(dataframe[i,"one"],split = ""))
    str2<-unlist(strsplit(dataframe[i,"two"],split = ""))
    for(j in 1:length(str1)){
      if(j <= length(str2) & str1[j] == str2[j]){
        retstr<-str1[(j+1):length(str1)]
      }else{
        break
      }
    }
    result[i]<-paste(retstr,collapse = "")
  }
  return(result)
}

getDiff(df)


results:
 "t" "p" ""
```

i don't know if is there any default function to do this... may be  this will be helpful...